# Rewind() and flip() methods in Buffer class

Tags: java, nio

I am having problem in understanding the following snippet. I am confused in visualizing the functionality of the rewind() and flip() of the [Buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#flip--) class. Assume that the file referred is empty initially.

```
String s = "I was here!\n";
byte data[] = s.getBytes();
ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

ByteBuffer copy = ByteBuffer.allocate(12);

try (FileChannel fc = (FileChannel.open(file, READ, WRITE))) {
    // Read the first 12
    // bytes of the file.
    int nread;
    do {
        nread = fc.read(copy);
    } while (nread != -1 && copy.hasRemaining());

    // Write "I was here!" at the beginning of the file.
    fc.position(0);
    while (out.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(out);
    out.rewind();

    // Move to the end of the file.  Copy the first 12 bytes to
    // the end of the file.  Then write "I was here!" again.
    long length = fc.size();
    fc.position(length-1);
    copy.flip();
    while (copy.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(copy);
    while (out.hasRemaining())
        fc.write(out);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.out.println("I/O Exception: " + x);
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Might help if you read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html). This is all properly explained in the documentation.

Comment: @Boris the Spider : As per the doc, A buffer's limit is the index of the first element that should not be read or written. A buffer's limit is never negative and is never greater than its capacity. Since the first element is always at 0 index location, when i allocate a buffer for 20 elements, it shows the limit to be 20. Why so?

Comment: The 'first element' and the 'first element that should not be read or written' don't refer to the same element. The first element is at zero; the first element that should not be read or written in your example is at 20.